# Wrong SQL Syntax; Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio that's hooked up to an Azure SQL database; usually, I'm used to using Oracle (It's just a rookie mistake I guess). What exactly am I doing wrong? These are the error messages that I'm getting:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 42
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 54
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 66
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE ElectiveCourses 
(
    ElectiveCourseID INT,
    ElectiveCoursePrefix CHAR(5),
    ElectiveCourseCode INT,
    ElectiveCreditHours INT,
    ElectiveCourseDescription VARCHAR(255),
    CatalogYearID INT,
    MajorID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (ElectiveCourseID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CatalogYearID, MajorID)
);

CREATE TABLE Major 
(
    MajorID INT, 
    MajorTitle VARCHAR(50),
    MajorCode INT,
    MajorLevel CHAR(5),
    MajorDescription VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (MajorID)
);

CREATE TABLE CatalogYear 
(
    CatalogYearID INT,
    CatalogYear VARCHAR(10),
    CatalogYearStartTerm VARCHAR(10),
    CatalogYearEndTerm VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (CatalogYearID)
);

CREATE TABLE Student 
(
    StudentID INT,
    FirstName CHAR(25),
    LastName CHAR(10),
    MajorID INT,
    CatalogYearID INT,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(15),
    AreaCode INT,
    Address VARCHAR(50),
    State CHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (StudentID),
    FOREIGN KEY (MajorID, CatalogYearID)
);

CREATE TABLE MajorCourses 
(
    MajorCourseID INT,
    MajorCoursePrefix CHAR(5),
    MajorCourseCode INT,
    MajorCreditHours INT,
    MajorCourseDescription VARCHAR(255),
    CatalogYearID INT,
    MajorID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (MajorCourseID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CatalogYearID, MajorID)
);

CREATE TABLE Courses   
(
    CourseID INT,
    CoursePrefix CHAR (5),
    CourseCode INT,
    CreditHours INT,
    CourseDescription VARCHAR(255),
    CatalogYearID INT,
    MajorID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (CourseID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CatalogYearID, MajorID)
);
```

Comment: The foreign key constraint columns are missing the referenced table name. I don't know what table that should be because you are missing a table with a primary key of CatalogYearID, MajorID in your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**WHAT** other table/column(s) do these foreign key reference?? You need to provide that info!

```
CREATE TABLE ElectiveCourses 
(
    .... all the columns ......
    PRIMARY KEY (ElectiveCourseID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CatalogYearID, MajorID) **REFERENCES dbo.OtherTable(col1, col2)**
);
```

Also, those references have to match a **whole, complete** primary key of another table - you cannot reference only parts of a (composite) primary key. The names, order, and datatype of the columns in the foreign key must **exactly match** the primary key of the table being referenced.

I didn't find any other table in your sample shown that has a primary key that's made up from `(CatalogYearID, MajorID)` - so this reference here (and some of the others, too) is very unclear  .....

And as a side note: I would **strongly recommend** to explicitly **name** your constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ElectiveCourses 
(
    .... all the columns ......
    CONSTRAINT PK_ElectiveCourses        
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ElectiveCourseID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ElectiveCourses_OtherTable
        FOREIGN KEY (CatalogYearID, MajorID) 
        REFERENCES dbo.OtherTable(col1, col2)
);
```

That makes it just soooo much easier to reference those constraints if you ever need to e.g. disable or drop them.